# Strange error on get values from geonames table

Tags: php, geonames

have this query:

```
$query="SELECT t1.*, t2.*, t3.*,t4.*,t5.*,t7.asciiname as asciiname_t7, t8.asciiname as asciiname_t8, t9.*
         FROM anunturi t1 
         INNER JOIN tranzactie t2 ON t1.tranzactie = t2.id_tranzactie
         INNER JOIN tip_proprietate t3 ON t1.tip = t3.id_prop
         INNER JOIN anunt_descriere t4 ON t1.id_anunt = t4.ext
         INNER JOIN anunt_locatie t5 ON t1.id_anunt = t5.ext
         INNER JOIN zone t9 ON t5.zona = t9.id_zona
         INNER JOIN locatii t7 ON t5.judet = t7.admin1_code AND t7.feature_code='ADM1'
         INNER JOIN locatii t8 ON t5.oras = t8.geonameid 
         WHERE t1.user=:code AND t1.status=:arh  ORDER  BY t1.data DESC";
```

and this query `

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `locatii` WHERE (`feature_code`=:code OR `feature_code`=:code2) AND `admin1_code`=:code3 ORDER BY `asciiname` ASC";
```

I get the result from the second query but I don't get results from the first query.
No error are displayed.

This is a  strange problem because on my wamp the both queries  are worked fine, but on the web server when my website is uploaded give me this problem.

I have imported the geonames table from my localhost to my webhosting phpmyadmin.

How can I fix it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I removed the t7 and t8 from the second query and the script display the values but when I put it back I receive the same problem.

Comment: Should you be getting results back from the first query? Does it run when you run it directly in the database?

Comment: In addition to questions by @andrewsi - what errors are in your error.log? And is displaying php errors turned on in your case?

Comment: How can I run directly in database?

Comment: Run the query from phpMyAdmin on your live server then you will see any errors. Otherwise check your mysql error log on the server.

Comment: The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay